# Disable Selecting Imaginary Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For I have two select boxes, one for Month (Jan-Dec) and one for Day (1-31).

**I want to disable the Month-Day combinations that don't exist**

- February 30 & 31
- April 31
- June 31
- September 31
- November 31

Code:

```
<sel><span>Month:</span>
    <select required name="month">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
</sel>
<br />

<sel><span>Day:</span>
    <select required name="day">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
</sel>
```

Jquery can do it but I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you select any option from the list it triggers a `change` event. You can bind an event to this change event and implement the logic to check the current month and day combination.

E.g

```
$('select[name="month"]').change(function () {
   var currentMonth = this.value;
   switch (currentMonth) {
     case '01'://for January
     case '02'://for February
       disableDay(30);
       disableDay(31);
     ...
     ...
   }
});
```

To diable any option in the select dropdownlist

```
$('select[name="day"]').find('option[value="31"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

So you can implement a function to disable day in the day dropdown list and call it appropriately on month dropdown change based on the month and pass the right day to disable.

```
function disableDay (day) {
   $('select[name="day"]').find('option[value="'+day+'"]').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a premade library https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, its easier and cleaner. Otherwise it will be lots of jquery, on month change, check dates, add/remove to match month....

Answer (score 0):

it is kinda ugly but it does what you asked for ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var m = $('select[name=month]');
  var d = $('select[name=day]');
  var hide31 = ['02','04','06','09','11'];
  var hide30 = ['02'];
  var d31 = d.find('[value=31]');
  var d30 = d.find('[value=30]');
  m.change(function(){
    var v = m.val();
    if (hide30.indexOf(v)>=0){  d30.hide();  }
    else { d30.show();  }
    if (hide31.indexOf(v)>=0){  d31.hide();  }
    else { d31.show();  }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is great! Idk why ShankarSangoli's answer wouldn't work, but since this is hiding the selections instead of disabling them, I would need to have the user select the Month first

Comment: It only hides day 30 and/or 31 or the month values in the array hide31 or hide30 are selected, so before a month is selected, all days should show, obviously this does not take into account leap year or anything like that, for that use a real calendar plug-in as others suggested.

Comment: If you like this answer please consider up-voting it or selecting it as the solution.

Comment: Also, as i said, although the answer "works" if you select the day first you can still select imaginary dates